# how to write months in javascript in proper manner

Tags: javascript

As of now i have made this function, but it looks lengthy and ugly. is there any way to generate the months dynamically or another Approach.

To better understand please see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/67/

```
 function formatMonth(d) {
        switch (d) {
        case 0:
            return "Jan";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "Feb";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "Mar";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "Apr";
            break;
        case 4:
            return "May";
            break;
        case 5:
            return "Jun";
            break;
        case 6:
            return "jul";
            break;
        case 7:
            return "Aug";
            break;
        case 8:
            return "Sep";
            break;
        case 9:
            return "Oct";
            break;
        case 10:
            return "Nov";
            break;
        case 11:
            return "Dec";
        default:
            return "Jan"
        }
    }


function (d) {
return formatMonth(d);
}
```

Comment: What about an array?

Comment: Use an array: month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar']

Comment: Use a array `return ["J","F","M"][d]`

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For a start, all of those `break` statements are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function formatMonth(d) {
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jul", "Jun", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    return month = months[d];
}

formatMonth(3)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6058zj9q/

Comment: How to add default month as "Jan"

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa do this? `function formatMonth() {
    return "Jan";
}`

Comment: This function unfortunately recreates the `months` array every time it is called. It would be better to use an IIFE, as in `var formatMonth = function() { var months = ["Jan", ...]; return function(d) { return months[d]; }; }();`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var formatMonth = function(i) {
  return ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jul", "Jun", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][i];
};
console.log(1, formatMonth(1));
console.log(0, formatMonth(0));
```

```html
Open console
```

Comment: Why use split!? Start with the array to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using the `moment` library, then it's

```
> moment.months(0)
"January"

> momenet.monthsShort(0)
"Jan"
```

Comment: i am not using moment library but the information you shared is appreciated thank you torazaburo